# How to download multiple files via PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files to download, as many as 7 at a time, it downloads the first file then peters out.

The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:17 char:5
$IE.Navigate2("https://mdf.mydomain.com/SeaNet//DownloadFile ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

```
$BinaryID = 7458,7457,7446,7317
# open IE
    $IE = New-Object -COMObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $IE.Visible = $True
    $MyUser = ""
    $MyCreds = Get-Credential -Credential $MyUser
    $MyPass = $Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    $IE.Navigate2("https://mdf.mydomain.com/SeaNet/CustomReport.aspx?reportId=692")
    While($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 30}
    $IE.document.getElementById('UserNameTB').value = "$MyUser"
    $IE.document.getElementById('PasswordTB').value = "$MyPass"
    $Link = $IE.Document.getElementByID('LoginIBtn')[0].Item().Click()

ForEach ($ID in $BinaryID) {
    $IE.Navigate2("https://mdf.mydomain.com/SeaNet/DownloadFile.aspx?binaryid=$ID")
    Pause
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry folks, line '17' in the error is line 15, I pulled a couple comments but didn't fix the error

Comment: I'm only guessing, but perhaps your approach requires synchronous, sequential operation; that is, perhaps you'll have to wait for each initiated download to complete before initiating the next.

Comment: Have you tried `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Start-BitsTransfer` ... Just be aware to set `$progresspreference = 0` before a invoke-eebrewuest download or it'll be painfully slow